# How to efficiently generate GSL matrices drawn from gaussian distributions?

Tags: matrix, random, gsl

What is the most efficient way in which one can generate a gsl matrix with entries drawn from Gaussian distributions?

I know about the function called `gsl_ran_gaussian` but, as far as I know, it only generates scalar values. I tried filling a matrix using that function in a double for loop, but it is very slow for my intended application.

I would like to generate 3xN matrices:
All the entries of the 1st 2 rows should be filled with samples from the same zero-mean Gaussian distribution of variance V1, while the entries of the last row should be filled with samples from a zero-mean Gaussian of variance V2.

**EDIT**:

This is how I am currently doing it:

```
gsl_matrix * M;
M = gsl_matrix_calloc(3, size2);
const gsl_rng_type * T;
gsl_rng * r;

gsl_rng_env_setup();
T = gsl_rng_default;
r = gsl_rng_alloc(T);

for (uint16_t k=0; k<size2; k++) {
    for (uint8_t h=0; h<2; h++)
        gsl_matrix_set(M, h, k, gsl_ran_gaussian(r,S1));
    gsl_matrix_set(M, 2, k, gsl_ran_gaussian(r,S2));
}
```

Comment: ". I tried filling a matrix using that function in a double for loop, but it is very slow for my intended application." -- Let's see the code!

Comment: This is embarrassingly parallel. The only non trivial part is to allocate one instance of the gsl_rng structure for each core.

Comment: @ AGS: you can check it in the edit above

@ViniciusMiranda: You are totally right! How didn't I even think about parallelizing?! However, I don't know how to split C code among different threads or cores. If someone can show me some example or point me to some useful link/tutorial on parallel coding in C, I would be very thankful :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12095564/openmp-and-c-parallel-for-loop-why-does-my-code-slow-down-when-using-openmp you can find a good discussion about that